# Mysql Query data filled check

Tags: sql, mysql-workbench, mysql

I had created the table with 200 columns and i had inserted data 
Now i need to check that specific 100 columns in one row are filled or not,how can we check this using mysql query .the primary key is defined .please help me out how to resolve this.

Comment: Try 


`SELECT IF(COLUMN1<>NULL, 'FILLED', 'NOT FILLED'), 
       IF(COLUMN2<>NULL, 'FILLED', 'NOT FILLED'),
       ...
       IF(COLUMN100<>NULL, 'FILLED', 'NOT FILLED'))
       FROM YOUR_TABLE`

It's tedious, I admit it

Comment: Probably, this is a problem of poor design.

Answer (score 0):

```
  select * from tablename where column1 != null or column2 != null ......
```

Answer (score 0):

That is a lot of columns so at the risk of being mysql server version specific you can use the information schema to get the column names and then write a SQL procedure or something in your chosen shell / language that iterates over them performing a test.

```
select distinct COLUMN_NAME as 'Field', IS_NULLABLE from information_schema.columns where TABLE_SCHEMA="YourDatabase" and TABLE_NAME="YourTableName" and TABLE_NAME not like "%view%" escape '!' ;
```

The example above will tell you the column name as "Field" and tell you if it can hold a NULL. Having the field name may give you a better way of automating a field name specific test.